Solving for the range of a function algebraically
I am trying to find the range of:
$$
\frac{x}{x^2-16}
$$
I first solved for y:
$$
y= \frac{x}{x^2-16}
$$
$$
y(x^2 -16) = x
$$
$$
yx^2 -16y = x
$$
$$
yx^2 -x -16y = 0
$$
I then used the quadratic equation and got:
$$
x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+64y^2}}{2y}
$$
Then I just need to find the domain of this function in order to get the range of the original function. The discriminant is always $\ge$ $0$ for all x, so the only constraint is that $ y \ne 0$, as y is in the denominator. So that should be the range for the original function, however, it is not, instead the range is $ y \in \mathbb{R}$. So do I only look at the discriminant and ignore the denominator?

Your range is the set of values of $y$ such that the equation
$$
yx^2-x-16y=0
$$
has a solution $x\neq \pm 4$. When $y=0$ your equation is linear in $x$ and is satisfied by $x=0$. Otherwise, it is satisfied by the values you found by solving the quadratic equation. Importantly, those values are $\neq \pm 4$ for any $y\neq 0$. Therefore, all real $y$'s are in the range.


I am trying to find the range of:
$$
\frac{x}{x^2-16}
$$

Alternative approach:
The first thing to realize is that both $~f(x) = x,~$ and $~f(x) = x^2 - 16~$ are continuous functions.  Therefore, so is the function
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 - 16} ~: ~x^2 - 16 \neq 0. \tag1 $$
I will use the expressions:
$a \to b^-~$ to represent that $~a~$ approaches $~b~$ from below.
$a \to b^+~$ to represent that $~a~$ approaches $~b~$ from above.
So, it is clear that (for example) as $~x \to 4^-,~$ that the numerator is positive and the denominator approaches $~0~$ from below.  Therefore, the quotient, $~f(x),~$ approaches $~-\infty.~$
Further, in a (small) neighborhood around $~0,~$ the denominator will approximately equal $~-16.~$  Therefore, as $~x \to 0^+,~$ the quotient, $~f(x),~$ is approaching $~0~$ from below.
Let $~D~$ denote the subset of the domain of $~f(x)~$ given by $~0 \leq x < 4.~$  Then, since $~f(x)~$ is a continuous function, you must have that the range of $~f(D)~$ is $~(-\infty, 0].~$
That is, for every non-positive value $~y,~$ there must be an element $~x \in D~$ such that $~f(x) = y.$

Similarly as $~x \to -4^+,~$ the numerator is negative and the denominator approaches $~0~$ from below.  Therefore, the quotient, $~f(x),~$ approaches $~+\infty.~$
Also, again similar to the analysis in the first portion of this answer, in a (small) neighborhood around $~0,~$ the denominator will approximately equal $~-16.~$  Therefore, as $~x \to 0^-,~$ the quotient, $~f(x),~$ is approaching $~0~$ from above.
Let $~E~$ denote the subset of the domain of $~f(x)~$ given by $~0 \geq x > -4.~$  Then, since $~f(x)~$ is a continuous function, you must have that the range of $~f(E)~$ is $~[0, +\infty).~$
That is, for every non-negative value $~y,~$ there must be an element $~x \in E~$ such that $~f(x) = y.$
Therefore, by consideration of the two subsets $~D~$ and $~E,~$ the range of $~f(x)~$ is all real numbers.
